# Rich JButton without using images

Tags: java, jbutton

I have spent most of my time trying to imitate a Material Design look (as I really like it) as shown for a button [here](http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html) :

I am struggling with making the **borders of the Jbutton rounded** and also adding a **shadow to the buttons**. I found a way of doing the rounded borders but the background of the JButton, but it's not stay within this.

```
public class LoginView {  
private Component mainPanel;
public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sign In to eVenture Books");
    frame.setSize(350, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    placeComponents(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);  

    }//End of Main()

private static class RoundedBorder implements Border {
private int radius;
RoundedBorder(int radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}

public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
    return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+1);
}

public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
    return true;
}


public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radius, radius);
}
}//End of Class RoundedBorder


private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username :");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    panel.add(userLabel);

    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(userText);

    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password :");
    passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
    panel.add(passwordLabel);

    JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
    passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
    panel.add(passwordText);

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("LOGIN");
    loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
            loginButton.setBackground(new Color(0xF06292));
            //loginButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(5));
            loginButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            loginButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
            //loginButton.setForeground(new Color(0xFAFAFA));
            //loginButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    panel.add(loginButton);

    JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
    registerButton.setBounds(180, 80, 80, 25);
            registerButton.setBackground(new Color(0xF06292));
            registerButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(5));
    panel.add(registerButton);

            JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
    quitButton.setBounds(95, 80, 80, 25);
            quitButton.setBackground(new Color(0x757575));
            //quitButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED)); 
            //quitButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(5));
            // quitButton.setOpaque(false);
    panel.add(quitButton);

            JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Sign in to eVenture Books");
            titleLabel.setBounds(10, 120, 200, 25);
            titleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Freestyle Script", 1, 18)); 
            titleLabel.setText("Sign In to eVenture Books");
            panel.add(titleLabel);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend a JButton class, then in extended calss override method paint(Graphics g).

In this method use the Graphics g object to draw your button.
You can cast the g Graohics to Graphics2D to get more drawing methods.
Inside paint() you can use getWidth() and getHeight() methods for dimensions of your button. To paint shadow and or rounded button you need to paint smaller button than his bounds and draw some shadow in the free space around, so the shadow stays part of the button. The bounds of the JButton afre always rectangle, you can make JButton look rounded by drawing filled circle inside it. Do not call super.paint() inside your paint. Also you may need to call setOpaque(false) on your Button, this ensures that before painting your JButton his background is repainted, so you can draw some transparent parts (the shadow, and the circle needs transient areas)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am looking into it! I have also heard that I could accomplish a lot using JavaFX but I can't seem to find anywhere near as much information on it.